# What is the actual meaning of velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, calculus, displacement

There's a scenario where a car is moving between two points **A and B** in a way that it first goes **30m north and then 20m south** in a time period of **10 seconds**.

Now the speed of the car comes out to be `5 m/s` while the velocity comes out to be `1m/s in the north direction`.

So my doubt is that when I say that the speed of car is 5m/s and the velocity is 1m/s towards north for the same car isn't it conflicting because throughout the journey the car was in one single motion and not two different motions so then how can the car travel 5meters per second and 1meter per second in north as well between two points A and B?

If we say that velocity tells us about the direction of the motion along with the magnitude then why isn't it that the velocity is just `5m/s{the speed} + some direction`. How is it that the car is able to travel 5 meters per unit second and at the same time travel 1 meter per unit second in some direction between the two same set of points?? {what happens to the remaining magnitude, where is it lost in the velocity??}

Also is it just that my understanding of the concept of velocity is wrong? If so please provide with a good definition for explaining the concept of velocity. Thanks!

Comment: You should copy the question in higher detail. The set of numbers you gave seems to be internally inconsistent. If it says 1m/s in the north direction then I can immediately give you the reasoning.

Comment: I think you’re being confused by average vs. instantaneous values. The speed and velocity given here are averages over 10 seconds. Physicists tend to be much more interested in instantaneous values. Instantaneous velocity is defined as the first time derivative of position.

Comment: *"throughout the journey the car was in one single motion and not two different motions"* No, the car had two different motions. It went north for 6 seconds, then it went south for 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into calculus, average velocity is total displacement divided by total time of the journey.  Average speed is total distance divided by total time.  Total displacement is the arrow that points from the start position to the end position, all the little displacement vector arrows added together into one total vector arrow.  Total distance can be what an odometer reads.  It can be the number of steps taken, all of the little distances added together.  It is the length of the path followed, regardless of direction.  A person can run around a one-mile track and end up at the starting point.  The person traveled a distance of one mile.  If this takes ten minutes, the the person's average speed is six miles per hour.  Displacement is zero.  The run around the track did not result in a total change of position at all.  Although velocity during the run was never zero, the average velocity is zero.  The eastward effects balance the westward effects.  The northward effects balance the southward effects.  We use both speed and velocity because each can be important, depending on what we are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that the instantaneous speed $v(t)$ is equal to the magnitude of the instantaneous velocity $\vec v(t),$
$$v(t)=\lvert\vec v(t)\rvert$$
this is not generally true for the average speed and velocity, over an interval $[t_1,t_2]$, which are given by averaging the instantaneous values over the interval.
$$v_{[t_1,t_2]} = \frac1{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathrm{d}t\,\lvert\vec v(t)\rvert
\ne \frac1{t_2-t_1}\left\lvert\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathrm{d}t\,\vec v(t)\right\rvert = \lvert\vec v_{[t_1,t_2]}\rvert$$
By the triangle inequality, it follows that average speed is greater than or equal to the magnitude of average velocity.

Answer (score 0):

In physics, velocity has a very specific meaning, defined as displacement divided by the time that it took to make that displacement, and that displacement must be in a constant direction.  In turn, displacement has a very specific meaning, defined as final position - initial position.  The stated problem involves an object that traveled a certain distance north, then reversed direction to travel a certain distance south.  Due to this, the displacement was somewhat less than the distance traveled, leading to a velocity calculation that is smaller than either speed that the object experienced.